# How to set value of Eclipse project variable dynamically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Is there a way to define a variable in Eclipse project properties (those which are referenced by ${VarName}) from file contents or command output?

E.g. I'd like to create a variable which gets its value from `git describe` so that I can attach git revision to the name of executable artifact. I know I can do it using post-build script but I'd like to know whether it can by done entirely by Eclipse.